# A Standard English Daily Routine

Tags: riddle, knowledge, lateral-thinking

> At 10:30, I shear some fleece.
> At 13:30, I grow a foot.
> At 16:00, I strut.
> At 16:30, I look at my palm.
> At 19:30, I set a trap.

What am I?

My first riddle involving lateral thinking, enjoy!

Subtle Hint:

> Clock hand, the hour one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> a linguist studying English pronunciation!

Explanation:

> Take the vowel chart of the International Phonetic Alphabet:
>  [image]
>  Look at the hour hand's direction at that time, and take the closest English vowel it's pointing to. Then the actions for that time are the [standard lexical set keywords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set):
>
>  `10:30` → `/i/` → `FLEECE`
>  `13:30` → `/ʊ/` → `FOOT`
>  `16:00` → `/ʌ/` → `STRUT`
>  `16:30` → `/ɑ/` → `PALM`
>  `19:30` → `/æ/` → `TRAP`